# Validate User-Input HTML Subset

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm looking for a way to validate user-input HTML, similar to what you'd see in a comment form. The user's input should be limited to the most basic tags, such as p, ul, li, div, img. The only allowable attribute is style.

Validation can occur clients-side, via Javascript, or server-side, via Ruby. I'm hoping to find a Javascript library that can do this, or at least find several RegExes to do this.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You'll need to validate on the server side regardless of whether you have client-side validation. There's absolutely nothing that's stopping users from messing with your script (via Firebug, for example) to work around client-side validation. With that said, having client side validation will make the page a lot more user friendly.

Comment: Style can be a dangerous attribute to allow unless you restrict what properties it can manipulate.  Since you are not allowing `<a>` tags it can't be used for click-jacking but it could still be used for other sorts of mischief such as covering the entire page: `<div style="top:0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: 9000; background: #000; color: #fff" >Nothing to see here.</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Sanitize](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize) to filter the HTML.

Using the example elements you listed in your question you would use something like this in your validation code:

```
Sanitize.clean(html,
    :elements => ['p', 'ul', 'li', 'div', 'img'],
    :attributes => {'
        'all' => ['style']
    }
)
```

As I mentioned in my comment above, allowing the `style` attribute could be dangerous especially if you allow `<a>` tags as it opens you up to [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) attacks if a user creates an invisible link that covers the entire page.

If you do want to allow `<a>` tags I would recommend banning `style` completely and perhaps adding `rel=nofollow` to user provided links:

```
Sanitize.clean(html,
    :elements => ['p', 'ul', 'li', 'div', 'img', 'a'],
    :add_attributes => {
      'a' => {'rel' => 'nofollow'}
    }
)
```

Comment: This is probably just what I want. Thank you! I'll give it a whirl.